# Copying files from remote to local using lftp in unix

Tags: shell-script, ftp, filter, lftp

I originally posted this in server fault, but it didn't get much traction. I'm hoping someone here can help.

I'm trying to write a script to copy some files from a remote ftp server to a local directory. Eventually I want to be able to filter by modified date, but for now I'm just trying to get a handle on a simple directory copy. I have seen lots of examples using the mirror command of lftp but so far none of them seem to work. Currently I have a command that looks like this:

```
lftp -u myuser ftp.myserver.net -e 'set ftp:ssl-allow no;mirror -c --verbose eyerep-test/outgoing/archive ~/eyerep-files/outgoing;quit;'
```

If I execute that command, it will connect to the server and try to run the mirror command, but when it finishes I don't see any files copied into the ~/eyerep-files/outgoing folder on my machine. I also tried connecting to the remote with lftp and running the commands one at a time. I got the same results. I'm not quite sure what I'm doing wrong here. Can anyone shed some light on why this command isn't working?

**Update:**
Just to make sure it wasn't an issue with the remote server, I decided to try running some commands against a public ftp server and see what happened.

I ran:

```
cd /home/pbuchheit/eyerep-files
lftp apache.cs.utah.edu
cd apache.org/zzz
mirror -c --transfer-all --verbose=2 --script=cmd.log
quit
```

The following commands were logged to the cmd.log file but when I look in the directory I don't actually see any of the files or directories that were supposedly copied.

```
get -O /home/pbuchheit/eyerep-files ftp://apache.cs.utah.edu/apache.org/zzz/HEADER
get -O /home/pbuchheit/eyerep-files ftp://apache.cs.utah.edu/apache.org/zzz/HEADER.html
get -O /home/pbuchheit/eyerep-files ftp://apache.cs.utah.edu/apache.org/zzz/HEADER.txt
get -O /home/pbuchheit/eyerep-files ftp://apache.cs.utah.edu/apache.org/zzz/README
get -O /home/pbuchheit/eyerep-files ftp://apache.cs.utah.edu/apache.org/zzz/README.html
get -O /home/pbuchheit/eyerep-files ftp://apache.cs.utah.edu/apache.org/zzz/README.txt
get -O /home/pbuchheit/eyerep-files ftp://apache.cs.utah.edu/apache.org/zzz/checkrev.py
get -O /home/pbuchheit/eyerep-files ftp://apache.cs.utah.edu/apache.org/zzz/find-ls.gz
get -O /home/pbuchheit/eyerep-files ftp://apache.cs.utah.edu/apache.org/zzz/status.json
get -O /home/pbuchheit/eyerep-files ftp://apache.cs.utah.edu/apache.org/zzz/time.txt
get -O /home/pbuchheit/eyerep-files ftp://apache.cs.utah.edu/apache.org/zzz/update-files.sh
mkdir file:/home/pbuchheit/eyerep-files/checker-tests
get -O /home/pbuchheit/eyerep-files/checker-tests ftp://apache.cs.utah.edu/apache.org/zzz/checker-tests/README.html
chmod 644 file:/home/pbuchheit/eyerep-files/checker-tests/README.html
mkdir file:/home/pbuchheit/eyerep-files/mirror-tests
get -O /home/pbuchheit/eyerep-files/mirror-tests ftp://apache.cs.utah.edu/apache.org/zzz/mirror-tests/1mb.img
get -O /home/pbuchheit/eyerep-files/mirror-tests ftp://apache.cs.utah.edu/apache.org/zzz/mirror-tests/1mb.img.7z
get -O /home/pbuchheit/eyerep-files/mirror-tests ftp://apache.cs.utah.edu/apache.org/zzz/mirror-tests/1mb.img.bz2
get -O /home/pbuchheit/eyerep-files/mirror-tests ftp://apache.cs.utah.edu/apache.org/zzz/mirror-tests/1mb.img.tar.gz
get -O /home/pbuchheit/eyerep-files/mirror-tests ftp://apache.cs.utah.edu/apache.org/zzz/mirror-tests/1mb.img.tgz
get -O /home/pbuchheit/eyerep-files/mirror-tests ftp://apache.cs.utah.edu/apache.org/zzz/mirror-tests/1mb.img.zip
get -O /home/pbuchheit/eyerep-files/mirror-tests ftp://apache.cs.utah.edu/apache.org/zzz/mirror-tests/Readme.txt
mkdir file:/home/pbuchheit/eyerep-files/mirror-tests/redirect-test
chmod 644 file:/home/pbuchheit/eyerep-files/mirror-tests/1mb.img
chmod 644 file:/home/pbuchheit/eyerep-files/mirror-tests/1mb.img.7z
chmod 644 file:/home/pbuchheit/eyerep-files/mirror-tests/1mb.img.bz2
chmod 644 file:/home/pbuchheit/eyerep-files/mirror-tests/1mb.img.tar.gz
chmod 644 file:/home/pbuchheit/eyerep-files/mirror-tests/1mb.img.tgz
chmod 644 file:/home/pbuchheit/eyerep-files/mirror-tests/1mb.img.zip
chmod 644 file:/home/pbuchheit/eyerep-files/mirror-tests/Readme.txt
chmod 755 file:/home/pbuchheit/eyerep-files/mirror-tests/redirect-test
mkdir file:/home/pbuchheit/eyerep-files/perms
get -O /home/pbuchheit/eyerep-files/perms ftp://apache.cs.utah.edu/apache.org/zzz/perms/file444
get -O /home/pbuchheit/eyerep-files/perms ftp://apache.cs.utah.edu/apache.org/zzz/perms/file644
get -O /home/pbuchheit/eyerep-files/perms ftp://apache.cs.utah.edu/apache.org/zzz/perms/file664
mkdir file:/home/pbuchheit/eyerep-files/perms/dir555
get -O /home/pbuchheit/eyerep-files/perms/dir555 ftp://apache.cs.utah.edu/apache.org/zzz/perms/dir555/file444
get -O /home/pbuchheit/eyerep-files/perms/dir555 ftp://apache.cs.utah.edu/apache.org/zzz/perms/dir555/file644
get -O /home/pbuchheit/eyerep-files/perms/dir555 ftp://apache.cs.utah.edu/apache.org/zzz/perms/dir555/file664
chmod 644 file:/home/pbuchheit/eyerep-files/perms/dir555/file444
chmod 644 file:/home/pbuchheit/eyerep-files/perms/dir555/file644
chmod 644 file:/home/pbuchheit/eyerep-files/perms/dir555/file664
mkdir file:/home/pbuchheit/eyerep-files/perms/dir755
get -O /home/pbuchheit/eyerep-files/perms/dir755 ftp://apache.cs.utah.edu/apache.org/zzz/perms/dir755/file444
get -O /home/pbuchheit/eyerep-files/perms/dir755 ftp://apache.cs.utah.edu/apache.org/zzz/perms/dir755/file644
get -O /home/pbuchheit/eyerep-files/perms/dir755 ftp://apache.cs.utah.edu/apache.org/zzz/perms/dir755/file664
chmod 644 file:/home/pbuchheit/eyerep-files/perms/dir755/file444
chmod 644 file:/home/pbuchheit/eyerep-files/perms/dir755/file644
chmod 644 file:/home/pbuchheit/eyerep-files/perms/dir755/file664
mkdir file:/home/pbuchheit/eyerep-files/perms/dir775
get -O /home/pbuchheit/eyerep-files/perms/dir775 ftp://apache.cs.utah.edu/apache.org/zzz/perms/dir775/file444
get -O /home/pbuchheit/eyerep-files/perms/dir775 ftp://apache.cs.utah.edu/apache.org/zzz/perms/dir775/file644
get -O /home/pbuchheit/eyerep-files/perms/dir775 ftp://apache.cs.utah.edu/apache.org/zzz/perms/dir775/file664
chmod 644 file:/home/pbuchheit/eyerep-files/perms/dir775/file444
chmod 644 file:/home/pbuchheit/eyerep-files/perms/dir775/file644
chmod 644 file:/home/pbuchheit/eyerep-files/perms/dir775/file664
mkdir file:/home/pbuchheit/eyerep-files/perms/dr-xr-xr-x
get -O /home/pbuchheit/eyerep-files/perms/dr-xr-xr-x ftp://apache.cs.utah.edu/apache.org/zzz/perms/dr-xr-xr-x/r-xr-xr-x
chmod 755 file:/home/pbuchheit/eyerep-files/perms/dr-xr-xr-x/r-xr-xr-x
chmod 644 file:/home/pbuchheit/eyerep-files/perms/file444
chmod 644 file:/home/pbuchheit/eyerep-files/perms/file644
chmod 644 file:/home/pbuchheit/eyerep-files/perms/file664
chmod 755 file:/home/pbuchheit/eyerep-files/perms/dir555
chmod 755 file:/home/pbuchheit/eyerep-files/perms/dir755
chmod 755 file:/home/pbuchheit/eyerep-files/perms/dir775
chmod 755 file:/home/pbuchheit/eyerep-files/perms/dr-xr-xr-x
mkdir file:/home/pbuchheit/eyerep-files/rsync-module
get -O /home/pbuchheit/eyerep-files/rsync-module ftp://apache.cs.utah.edu/apache.org/zzz/rsync-module/apache-dist
chmod 644 file:/home/pbuchheit/eyerep-files/rsync-module/apache-dist
chmod 644 file:/home/pbuchheit/eyerep-files/HEADER
chmod 644 file:/home/pbuchheit/eyerep-files/HEADER.html
chmod 644 file:/home/pbuchheit/eyerep-files/HEADER.txt
chmod 644 file:/home/pbuchheit/eyerep-files/README
chmod 644 file:/home/pbuchheit/eyerep-files/README.html
chmod 644 file:/home/pbuchheit/eyerep-files/README.txt
chmod 755 file:/home/pbuchheit/eyerep-files/checkrev.py
chmod 755 file:/home/pbuchheit/eyerep-files/update-files.sh
chmod 755 file:/home/pbuchheit/eyerep-files/checker-tests
chmod 755 file:/home/pbuchheit/eyerep-files/mirror-tests
chmod 755 file:/home/pbuchheit/eyerep-files/perms
chmod 755 file:/home/pbuchheit/eyerep-files/rsync-module
```

**Update 2**

As suggested by @aviro, I tried running a strace to see what was going on under the hood. The command is:

> strace -f -yy -e trace=file -q -o lftp.strace lftp myuser@ftp.myserver.net

When I ran a mirror command I got the output:

```
429   openat(AT_FDCWD, ".", O_RDONLY|O_DIRECTORY) = 5</home/pbuchheit/eyerep-files>
429   getcwd("/home/pbuchheit/eyerep-files", 4096) = 29
429   chdir("/home/pbuchheit/eyerep-files") = 0
429   chdir("/home/pbuchheit/eyerep-files") = 0
429   chdir("/home/pbuchheit/eyerep-files") = 0
429   openat(AT_FDCWD, "/home/pbuchheit/eyerep-files", O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK|O_CLOEXEC|O_DIRECTORY) = 6</home/pbuchheit/eyerep-files>
429   lstat("/home/pbuchheit/eyerep-files/.", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0775, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
429   openat(AT_FDCWD, "/etc/passwd", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 6</etc/passwd>
429   openat(AT_FDCWD, "/etc/group", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 6</etc/group>
429   lstat("/home/pbuchheit/eyerep-files/..", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
429   lstat("/home/pbuchheit/eyerep-files/cmd.log", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0664, st_size=0, ...}) = 0
429   lstat("/home/pbuchheit/eyerep-files/lftp.strace", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0664, st_size=14407, ...}) = 0
429   openat(AT_FDCWD, "/etc/localtime", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 5</usr/share/zoneinfo/posixrules>
429   stat("/etc/localtime", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=3545, ...}) = 0
429   stat("/etc/localtime", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=3545, ...}) = 0
```

and the rest of the output is just a repeat of the last line several thousand times.

**Update 3:**

I pulled in someone else from my team to help test this. He had a virtual box with the same version of Ubuntu as me, and when he tested lftp got the same results. He also tested on an older version (16.04) and it worked there. Since it worked on the older version, I'm really thinking it has to do with the timezone settings but I'm still not sure how to fix it.

Comment: ~/eyerep-files/outgoing . I'll go ahead and update that.

Comment: Does `lftp -u myuser ftp.myserver.net -e 'set ftp:ssl-allow no;dir eyerep-test/outgoing/archive;quit'` return the expected list of files?

Comment: Yes. I see a list of the files in the archive directory.

Comment: Silly question - you're not getting errors are you

Comment: No errors. The command executes and it even creates the local directory if it doesn't exist. It just doesn't copy any of the files.

Comment: Does your user have read rights on the remote server?

Comment: As far as I know yes. Is there a way to verify that?

Comment: Verify that you can copy a single file using `get` rather than `mirror`

Comment: Copying a file with get works with no problem. I also double checked the permissions on the directory I'm trying to mirror and its the same as the files.

Comment: Do you have enough free space on the partition holding the "local" directory where you are mirroring files to? Is the "local" directory actually on a network mount or in any way special (nonstandard fs)? Do you have disk quotas active?

Comment: Also, what are the permissions and ownership of the "local" directory where you are mirroring files to?

Comment: @ Vilinkameni For now I'm just copying to a folder on my work computer and I have plenty of space available. As far as permissions go, the target directory on local is owned by me and I have read and write permissions.

Comment: In that case, this is a weird bug. I tried to mirror a directory from my FTP server in a similar way and it worked without error. I would [report this upstream](https://github.com/lavv17/lftp/issues).

Comment: I have few suggestions. First, I suggest to run your lftp command under strace: `strace -f -yy -e trace=file -q -o lftp.strace <command>`. This will write the lftp strace log to `lftp.strace`, where you can check `open`/`write` system calls and see if it tries to open any files for writing, and if it has any errors.  I also propose to try mirror to a different folder. Let's say, to /tmp, and check if the result is different.

Comment: @ aviro I added the output of the strace command to the post. I'm not seeing any obvious errors, but I also don't see anywhere that it actually tries to mirror. It seems to be getting hung up doing stat("/etc/localtime")

Comment: Does `/etc/localtime` exist? It should normally be a symbolic link to `/usr/share/zoneinfo/<Continent>/<City>`.

Comment: It does exist but it's a bit strange. It's a symlink that ultimately points to posixrules. I created a question with more details here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/688719/is-it-normal-for-timezone-to-symlink-to-posixrules?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: If you think this is somehow related to the timezone settings, there's extremely easy way to test it: Just change them! To whatever! Even delete `/etc/localtime`, just to check the result! Try anything, you've got nothing to lose. And since it worked on an older version, and your conclusion was it was related to the timezone settings, I assume that you reached this conclusion by checking the timezone settings on the older version and discovered they were different (it's the only reason for you to reach this conclusion). So why don't you try to apply the same configuration on the new version?

Comment: And also, eventually it might just turn up as a bug, as  [@Vilinkameni](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/687867/copying-files-from-remote-to-local-using-lftp-in-unix#comment1301682_687867) suggested, and the different behavior between the versions strongly affirms this suggestion. And if it's indeed a bug, we probably can't help you here and your best course of action would be to report it.